# which of the following holds?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be the closure in $C[0,1]$ of the set $B$ where

$$B =\{ f \in C[0,1] :  |f(x)|\le 1 \text{ and } |f'(x)| \le 1  \text{ for all } x \in [0,1]\}$$

then $A$ is which of these?

Connected, Compact, closed, dense.

i know it is closed being closure but how to look for others?

Comment: $C[0,1]$ cannot be all continuous functions? Why would the derivative exist?

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try to apply the definitions? Did it work? What criteria of density/compactness do you know? Do they work here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B: = \{f \in C[0,1] | f \text{ is differntiable on the whole interval and } ||f||_{\infty} \le 1 , ||f'||_{\infty} \le 1\}$

- Connected

  We know that $B$ is pathwise connected, since it's convex: $\forall f, g \in B, \theta f + (1-\theta) g \in B.$ It is a general result that the closure of a connected set is connected.
- Compact

  You have to apply Ascoli- Arzelà theorem. Then you know that $B$ is relatively compact. Hence the closure is compact.
- Dense

  Can you approximate any continuous function with function which are bounded by 1? For example could you approximate $h(x) = 2?$

Comment: i got your point. but for compact still doubt in my mind. i know azrela ascoli   .. but how to apply that

Comment: Ascoli-Arzelà says that if a set is equibounded and equicontinuous, then it is relatively compact. Can you show that this set is equibounded? (it should be easy). Why is it equicontinuous? What do derivatives have to do with equicontinuity?

Comment: yes azrela ascoli says that set will have a sequence which is uniformly convergent

Comment: derivatives gives equicontinuous

Comment: Since the derivatives are bounded you get equicontinuity (by Lagrange). If this is what you mean, then you are right :)

Comment: yes that is what i am saying